# Unable to open man pages

Tags: linux, sles

We have a newly cloned SLES 12 server on a VMware stack.  Since the migration, all attempts to open a man page results in the following error message:

```
/usr/bin/nroff: Can't create temp directory, exiting...
Manual page alias(1p) line 1/1 (END)
```

As a side note, non-root users have also been unable to ssh from this server to other servers on our network, resulting in a vague `Permission denied` message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We solved the problem by correcting the permissions on /tmp which was not mounted properly after the clone.  Simple mistake.
Before:

```
drwx------  19 root    root    16384 Nov  8 10:40 tmp
```

After:

```
drwxrwxrwt  19 root    root    16384 Nov  8 10:45 tmp
```

This solved both the problem opening man pages as well as the issue trying to ssh from that server.